# How can i get locale info in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, locale, region

I am developing a project with Unity 2019.2b, it is expected to work at all platforms (android, ios, windows, macos) , i am trying to get device locale info(e.g. en-us, en-au, en-bz) but all i can find is Application.systemLanguage definition. Even i decide to use this information i will still need region info. Are there any sample or way to get locale info in Unity or to get device region info? (If the solution for only region info; I dont want to use device location or dont want to use user ip address, i want to get it from settings)

I tried to get locale or at least device region info with RegionInfo,CultureInfo,System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture definitions, but it didn't work.

```
string regionName = System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.Name;
string cultureName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
string cname = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
string uiname = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
```

Depending on the platform (ios, android, windows,macos) sometimes the result comes as InvariantCulture, sometimes always en-US even device locale is not en-US.

Comment: The only info that you can get from SystemLanguage is in this list of enum: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html I'm not sure Unity is able to get more specific informations

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coming from Mono, used by Unity.

I found a few solutions in this [forum thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/getting-users-language-preference.5452/).

If you are working with Windows a workaround might be using PInvoke:

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
 private static extern int GetSystemDefaultLCID();
```

And then check the global culture like so:

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo(GetSystemDefaultLCID());
```

This might be used to set the culture:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(GetSystemDefaultLCID());
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(GetSystemDefaultLCID());
```

Comment: Never tried but you also might want to switch to ILCPP instead of Mono under Edit/ProjectSettings/PlayerSettins/OtherSettings/ScriptingBackend